# Redirecting a link to a diffrent link in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect these links to their target links

`example.com/a` => `example.com/b`

`example.com/c` => `example.com/d`

`example.com/d` => `example.com/e`

with Htaccess? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in your public_html/.htaccess file

```
Redirect /a /b 
Redirect /b /c
Redirect /c /d
Redirect /d /e
```